# TypeORM customrepository loosing context of the app and getting functions as undefined

Tags: nestjs, typeorm

I don't know if this can really be achieved but I want to know if there is a workaround to do it.

I'm managing my app with NestJS and TypeORM. As I'll manage a lot of database calls I thought it'd be a great idea to have a customrepository where all the other repositories can extend and there have all the common functions that I have.

so,

```
import { FindOneOptions, FindOptionsWhere, Repository } from 'typeorm';
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { mapWhere } from '../config/database/typeorm/typeorm.util';

@Injectable()
export class CustomRepository<Entity> extends Repository<Entity> {
  findOneOr404 = async (options: FindOneOptions<Entity>): Promise<Entity> => {
    try {
      // set the options
      const where: FindOptionsWhere<Entity> | FindOptionsWhere<Entity>[] = mapWhere(options.where);
      const findOneOptions: FindOneOptions<Entity> = {
        ...options,
        where,
      };
      return this.findOneOrFail(findOneOptions);
    } catch (err) {
      //throw new ResourceNotFoundException(entityName, err);
    }
  };
  /*  async findOneOr404(options: FindOneOptions<Entity>): Promise<Entity> {
    try {
      // set the options
      const where: FindOptionsWhere<Entity> | FindOptionsWhere<Entity>[] = mapWhere(options.where);
      const findOneOptions: FindOneOptions<Entity> = {
        ...options,
        where,
      };
      return this.findOneOrFail(findOneOptions);
    } catch (err) {
      //throw new ResourceNotFoundException(entityName, err);
    }
  }*/
}
```

this is my custom repository file and now the service

```
@Injectable()
export class UserExtService implements CrudService<User> {
  private readonly entityName = 'User';
  private readonly logger = new Logger(UserExtService.name);
  constructor(
    @Inject(REQUEST) private readonly request: Request,
    @InjectRepository(User)
    private usersRepository: CustomRepository<User>,
  ) {
    this.findOne = this.findOne.bind(this);
  }

  private get user(): User {
    return this.request.user;
  }

  //#region CRUD methods

  async createOne(dto: CreateUserDto): Promise<User> {
    return null;
  }

  async findOne(id: Id, parsedQuery?: ParsedQuery<User>): Promise<User> {
    const findOneOptions = getFindOneOptionsFromParsedQuery(parsedQuery);
    const where = {
      ...findOneOptions.where,
      id,
    };
    return this.usersRepository.findOneOr404({ ...findOneOptions, where });
  }
}
```

My main issue here is that when I call the `findOne` function inside the service all I get is that findOneOr404 is undefined BUT if I use a function that is built in the repository I can use it as it is.

Is there anyoption to prevent this from happening?

Tx in advc

Comment: How have you told TypeORM about the custom class? The `@Injectbale()` is to make Typescript reflect metadata for Nest to read, and`@InjectRepository()` generally reads back to `datasource.getRepository(entity)`

Comment: How should I? I read about the repository.extend but I wasn’t able to implement it yet. Is there any option that you think it could work?